# Civicrm update failed - from 5.19.2 to 5.29.0 - Drupal7 error log - page not found

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Update failed - Get initial upgrade screen with message template warnings & The database will be upgraded from 5.19.2 to 5.29.0.. ..see screenshot of following page when I click "Upgrade Now". Screen distorted (see below) and stops. Upgrade doesn't work.

Drupal error log - first of many messages - "page not found"

Example:
LOCATION    https://mysite.org/drupal//home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css
REFERRER    https://mysite.org/drupal/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1
MESSAGE home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: D7 or D8 (maybe obvious to others, but maybe not)

Comment: Drupal 7.72, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check you drupal directory path in your apache/nginx conf. If its different than 'home/mysite/public_html/drupal' either you can change in apache/nginx conf or replace $civicrm_root and template_c path in civicrm.settings.php

Or add below line at the end of the file in civicrm.settings.php

```
global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['url'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . 'sites/all/modules/civicrm/';
```

NOTE: make sure you have '/' at the end for CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL value.

Comment: I added the lines as suggested in civicrm.settings.php and the update proceeded perfectly.

global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['url'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . 'sites/all/modules/civicrm/';

I was unable to find the apache/nginx conf files. I assume they are not available to me from the host.

Comment: This also fixed another issue I had where ckeditor had disappeared from within Civi. It has now returned.

Do I need to maintain this fix forever? How could this issue have happened?